Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.13.0:compile (default-compile) on project: Compilation failure:
I'm encountering an error when trying to clean or build my maven project. The error is in regards to getter/setters from my models which have the @Data annotation at the top. Even though they are bundled in @Data, I attempted to include @Getter and @Setter within the models to see if anything would change to no avail.
Full Error:
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.155 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-11-02T15:07:27Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.13.0:compile (default-compile) on project: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/**/Documents/**/projects/**/src/main/java/com/example/**/controller/Controller.java:[88,14] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method setImageUrl(java.lang.String)
[ERROR]   location: variable album of type com.example.**.model.**
[ERROR] /Users/**/Documents/**/projects/**/src/main/java/com/example/**/controller/Controller.java:[99,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method setImageUrl(java.lang.String)
[ERROR]   location: variable newAlbum of type com.example.**.model.**

Now, I have made adjustments to pom.xml according to posts suggestions but that does not seem to do anything. They only change that has occurred is updating Java from 21.0.4 -> 21.0.5. Reverting back to 21.0.4 doesn't change anything. In addition, I've tried invalidating the cache and restarting.
Here is my full pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>**</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>**</name>
    <description>**</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.34</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudinary-http45</artifactId>
            <version>1.39.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudinary-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.39.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

EDIT:
The build is success for mvn clean but does not work for mvn package:
 mvn clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< com.example:** >---------------------
[INFO] Building ** 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- clean:3.3.2:clean (default-clean) @ ** ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/**/Documents/**/projects/**/target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.851 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-11-02T15:30:01Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

EDIT 2:
I would like to note that this application is an api which was working perfectly until I made an adjustment to prevent an error occurring for my UI. Reverting back to the previous changes does not allow the compile to work

The issue was resolved by adjusting the maven complier plugin configuration to ensure compatibility with Java 21 and specify the Lombok version. Also, removing the exclusion of Lombok from the Spring Boot Maven Plugin prevented potential conflicts during the build process:
 <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                <version>1.18.34</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>


Great ! Superb!!!

Change Lombok scope as compile shown below
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.34</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>


Based on error logs either of following could be the issue

Please validate variable imageUrl present in Album class

If this field is already present and if you are using IntelliJ IDEA
please check lombok plugin is installed



Variables are present and lombok plugin is installed
